# Rails 2 to rails 3 link_to image_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, link-to

This is the code that I use in rails 2

```
<%= link_to_remote image_tag("icon_edit.png", :onmouseover=>"$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').show()",:onmouseout=>"$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').hide()" ).html_safe, :url => { :controller =>'/resume/contact_detail',:action => 'edit_contact_detail'}, :html => { :class  => "link_grey" },:before => "$('edit_contact_link').hide();show_spinner('view_contact_detail','view_contact_detail_spinner')"  %>
```

How can I make it to rails 3 ?

I am new to unobtrusive javascript so someone can help me in converting this ?

I tried using the following :

```
<%= link_to  :url => { :controller =>'/resume/contact_detail',:action => 'edit_contact_detail'}, :remote=>true do %>
   <%= image_tag('icon_edit.png', :onmouseover=>"$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').show()",:onmouseout=>"$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').hide()") %>
<% end %>
```

But I am missing the :before option :(

Thank you

Comment: also remote=:true doesn't make it remote. the call is done like normal html call

Comment: You need to have `rails.js` in your layout, and the `csrf_meta_tag` in your layout for remote to work.

Comment: Thanks I had included that already. But still it doesn't make a remote call . But the tags generated have the remote tags as true :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `:before` as you would do in Rails 2.X, define it as a `:onclick`.

```
<%= link_to  :url => { :controller =>'/resume/contact_detail',:action => 'edit_contact_detail'}, :remote => true, :onclick => "$('edit_contact_link').hide();show_spinner('view_contact_detail','view_contact_detail_spinner')" do %>
   <%= image_tag('icon_edit.png', :onmouseover=>"$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').show()",:onmouseout=>"$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').hide()") %>
<% end %>
```

The `onclick` event should be run before the `:remote` call.

See my comment on your question as to why the remote part isn't running.

Comment: the following code gets generated : 
<a href="/resume?onclick=%24%28%27edit_contact_link%27%29.hide%28%29%3Bshow_spinner%28%27view_contact_detail%27%2C%27view_contact_detail_spinner%27%29&amp;remote=true&amp;url[action]=edit_contact_detail&amp;url[controller]=%2Fresume%2Fcontact_detail">
   <img alt="Icon_edit" onmouseout="$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').hide()" onmouseover="$(this).up('.tooltip-wrapper').down('.tooltip-wrapper-box').show()" src="/images/icon_edit.png?1304679895" />
</a>

Comment: onclick is a wonderful idea . thanks for that.
I have page.replace method in my _edit_contact_detail.rjs file
that shouldn't be a prob right ?